# HTML Links not working in hotmail

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, hotmail

I'm currently building a application which sends some url's to our users by email. Though it seems that Hotmail is blocking the urls resulting in a redirect to their Inbox. I can't find a solution. Url is looking like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/example/32/Iew12">http://www.example.com/example/32/Iew12</a>
```

Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: Are the URL's pointing to a domain or an IP address?

Comment: Is the URL/IP address on a black list? I don't see much of a problem with what you've put....

Comment: Generally good first question, but avoid signing your questions.

Comment: "*blocking the urls resulting in a redirect to their Inbox*" What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

The link looks fine so I would say it's more likely this is a security feature within hotmail.  Are the emails going to the users junk mail?  I don't think there's anything you can do other than make sure your recipients have your reply email address on their whitelist and they enable links to be clicked within the email.

Comment: The email is indeed going to the spambox. I'll look into fixing this to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: yeah I would start there, whitelisting is probably what needs to happen.